# Login with php and html

Tags: php, html, authentication

I am making a login page using html and php, i did a simple one which was working fine using these code :

HTML
    
    
      
        
        Login Form

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">




 </head>

 <body>

  <div class="login">
<div class="login-triangle"></div>

  <h2 class="login-header">Login</h2>

 <form class="login-container" method="post" action="Login.php">
   <p><input type="text" id="username" name="username"        placeholder="Username"></p>

    <p><input type="password" id="password" name="password"    placeholder="Password"></p>
     <p><input type="submit" value="Login"></p>
  </form>
</div>
  <script    src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>


  </body>
 </html>
```

PHP

```
<?php
include ("dbconfig.php");
session_start();
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbconfig, $_POST['username']); //to clean up, to avoid sql injection
//$name = md5($name);


$pw = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbconfig, $_POST['password']);
 //  $pw = md5($pw);


$sql_query="SELECT userid FROM user WHERE username='$name' AND password='$pw'";
$result = mysqli_query($dbconfig, $sql_query);
$row = mysqli_Fetch_array ($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$count = mysqli_num_rows ($result);
 if ($count >0){
    $_SESSION['Login'] = $name;
    header ("location:Welcome.php");
 }
 if($count == 1)
  {
    echo "wrong login details";
  }

?>
```

But when i try to do the login with a new html file using the same php file it wont work at all, it keep saying "wrong login details" even though i am putting the right login in.

Here is the new html, i am thinking maybe it has to do with the additional classes which was added.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Kate's World Sign In</title>

    <!-- Google Fonts -->
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?     family=Roboto+Slab:400,100,300,700|Lato:400,100,300,700,900'    rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css">
    <!-- Custom Stylesheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

     <script   src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js">  </script>
</head>

<body>
    <Form  method="post" action="Login.php">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="top">
            <h1 id="title" class="hidden"><span id="logo">Log <span>In</span></span></h1>
        </div>
        <div class="login-box animated fadeInUp">
            <div class="box-header">
                <h2>Log In</h2>
            </div>
            <label for="username">Username</label>
            <br/>
            <input type="text" id="username" name="username" >
            <br/>
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <br/>
            <input type="password" id="password" name="password">
            <br/>
            <button type="submit">Sign In</button>
            <br/>
        </div>
        </div>
    </Form>
</body>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#logo').addClass('animated fadeInDown');
        $("input:text:visible:first").focus();
    });
    $('#username').focus(function() {
        $('label[for="username"]').addClass('selected');
    });
    $('#username').blur(function() {
        $('label[for="username"]').removeClass('selected');
    });
    $('#password').focus(function() {
        $('label[for="password"]').addClass('selected');
    });
    $('#password').blur(function() {
        $('label[for="password"]').removeClass('selected');
    });
</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the additional classes should not effect your PHP code.

To solve the problem, you need to see what you are receiving on the PHP side. Stick in a few tests - echo out some data. First, at the very beginning. Then, when you know for sure what is comign through, move your tests down the file a bit. Work out all the bugs, then remove all the tests.

For example, start by modifying your PHP like this:

```
    <?php
        session_start();
        include ("dbconfig.php");
        $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbconfig, $_POST['username']); //to clean up, to avoid sql injection
    echo 'Name: ' . $name. '<br>';

        $pw = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbconfig, $_POST['password']);
    echo 'Password: ' . $pw. '<br>';

    die();
```

Then, move down the file a bit and do this:

```
    $sql_query="SELECT userid FROM user WHERE username='$name' AND password='$pw'";
    $result = mysqli_query($dbconfig, $sql_query);
    $row = mysqli_Fetch_array ($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $count = mysqli_num_rows ($result);
echo 'Rows found: ' .$count. '<br>';

    if ($count >0){
echo 'Inside count > 0<br>';
        $_SESSION['Login'] = $name;
        header ("location:Welcome.php");
    }else{
echo 'Inside count ELSE<br>';
        echo "wrong login details";
    }
```

---

Notes:

1. PHP `header()` method will not work if other header messages have been sent. Alternative: `echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://new.example.com/address" />';`
2. Note McKenzma's observations about your `if ($count >0){` code: both IF statements will be true if `$count==1`.
3. Note that `session_start()` should be ***the very first*** instruction in your PHP file. *See my example code above*

Comment: When i try this using the first html form it does echo out the username and password but with the second html file it just goes to "wrong details" again, this is so weird

Comment: Add more `echo` statements to clearly trace the program flow in the PHP file. As you improve, you can also look into [FirePHP](https://github.com/firephp/firephp) (a Firebug for PHP, works best in Firefox but also works in Chrome). However, you might spend hours getting it set up and the manual `echo` method should find the solution in minutes. FirePHP is good to know about, though.

Answer (score 0):

Your 2nd conditional should be "$count != 1".  You want to return exactly one row for a successful login.

Comment: Do you mean != instead of <> ?

Answer (score 0):

You should have used if and else, not if and if.

```
<?php
 $count = mysqli_num_rows ($result);
if ($count >0){
$_SESSION['Login'] = $name;
header ("location:Welcome.php");
} else {
echo "wrong login details";
}
?>
```